# Mixed let/const array destructuring from split string

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6

TS throws an error:

```
'parsedHours' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead    prefer-const
'parsedMinutes' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead  prefer-const
```

When trying to deconstruct this array, after a string split:

```
let [
  parsedHours = '00',
  parsedMinutes = '00',
  parsedSeconds = '00',
  parsedMillis = '000'
] = "12:34:56".split(':');

if (parsedSeconds.includes('.')) {
  [parsedSeconds, parsedMillis] = parsedSeconds.split('.');
}
```

**Hours** and **minutes** should be declared as constants, but **Seconds** and **Millis** may change, thus should be declared as let.
This can be fixed in many approaches, but I can't find a beautiful way of doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: `// @ts-ignore` IMO

Comment: *"TS throws error"* I'm 99% TypeScript is not what's complaining here. TSLint or ESLint, but not TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.split()` with a RegExp to split by `[.:]`:

```js
const splitTime = (str) => {
  const [
    parsedHours = '00',
    parsedMinutes = '00',
    parsedSeconds = '00',
    parsedMillis = '000'
  ] = str.split(/[.:]/);

  console.log({
    parsedHours,
    parsedMinutes,
    parsedSeconds,
    parsedMillis
  });
}

splitTime("12:34:56")

splitTime("12:34:56.35")
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought while I was dog-walking. Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have a couple of options:

1. Turn off the lint rule (I'm 99% sure it's not TypeScript itself saying this, but TSLint or ESLint or similar).
2. Save the array, then use `const` or `let` as desired.
3. Use `const` for all of them by using a regular expression (perhaps with named capture groups) that handles the possible formats you're feeding it.

Here's #2:

```
const result = "12:34:56".split(":");
const [parsedHours = "00", parsedMinutes = "00"] = result;
let [, , parsedSeconds = "00", parsedMillis = "000"] = result;
// ...
```

Here's #3:

```js
const rexTime = /^(?<hours>\d{1,2}):(?<minutes>\d{1,2}):(?<seconds>\d{1,2})(?:\.(?<millis>\d{1,3}))?$/;
function example(timeString) {
    const {
        groups: {
            hours = "00",
            minutes = "00",
            seconds = "00",
            millis = "000"
        } = {}
    } = rexTime.exec(timeString) ?? {};
    console.log(
        timeString,
        "=>",
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds,
        millis
    );
}

example("12:34:56");
example("12:34:56.123");
```

There are a dozen different ways to spin that, that's just one of them, but it gives you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason Seconds and Millis *may* change is because of that single `if` block, then your approach is flawed in the first place. This is because on the initial `split`, `parsedSeconds` isn't actually "parsed seconds", it's "parsed seconds with optional decimal part".

Instead, consider parsing your actual format, in this case with regex:

```js
const [
  , // ignore "full match"
  parsedHours,
  parsedMinutes,
  parsedSeconds,
  parsedMillis = "000"
] = "12:34:56".match(/^(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?:\.(\d{3}))?$/) || [];
```

In this scenario, all the parsed pieces are indeed constant.

Note that final `|| []`, which catches the case where the input is not in an expected format. You could call the full match `parsedResult` and test `if( !parsedResult) throw 'something';`

Comment: Yeah, I also went back and threw regex at it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Classic XY problem, right? :D "How do I mix `let` and `const`?" "Why do you want to?"

Answer (score 0):

Why not replacing the `.` with the `:` and split all over? (if you don't want to do that, the second sample exclude the . replace)

Btw you can just have the rest spreaded as const, and then let the sub ones:

```js
const [
  parsedHours = '00',
  parsedMinutes = '00',
  ...rest
] = "12:34:56.123".replace('.', ':').split(':');
let [
  parsedSeconds = '00',
  parsedMillis = '000'
] = rest;  

   console.log(rest);

const [
  parsedHours2 = '00',
  parsedMinutes2 = '00',
  ...rest2
] = "12:34:56.123".split(':');
let [
  parsedSeconds2 = '00',
  parsedMillis2 = '000'
] = rest2;  

console.log(rest2);
```